# calculating the integral $\int_1^2 \frac{1}{x}$ using Darboux sum

Tags: integration, riemann-sum

I wish to calculate the integral $\int_1^2 \frac{1}{x}$ using Darboux sum using the division $p_n=2^{\frac{j}{n}}, 0\le j\le n$

I tried calculating the upper sum:

$$U(f,p_n)=\sum_{j=1}^n(2^{\frac jn}-2^{\frac{j-1}{n}})({2^{-\frac{j-1}{n}}})= \sum_{j=1}^n(2^{\frac 1n}-1)=n(2^{\frac{1}{n}}-1)$$

This should converge to $\ln(2)$ although I don't know how to show it.

have I done it right? how should I proceed?

Comment: Relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1742954/evaluating-a-certain-integral-without-the-fundamental-theorem

Comment: @Robert I can't see how this is helps when $n=-1$

Comment: You have reduced the integration problem to a differentiation problem, do you see why?

Comment: @Ian no, why is that?

Comment: Because the terms in the sum are all the same so you are left to compute $\lim_{n \to \infty} n(2^{1/n}-1)=\lim_{x \to 0} (2^x-1)/x$.

Comment: @Ian I know see it! thanks!

Comment: @segevp, if an answer is already obvious ($\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{2^x-1}{x}=\ln2$), would you please edit your question or maybe even answer it?

Comment: @TonyMa I answered it now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

continuing from where I stopped:

$U(f,p_n)= \sum_{j=1}^n(2^{\frac 1n}-1)=n(2^{\frac{1}{n}}-1 )$

Taking the limit I get: 
$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}n(2^{\frac{1}{n}}-1 )=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{2^x-1}{x}=\ln(2)$

Using the same idea I get $L(f,p_n)$ is also $\ln(2)$

Therefore $U(f,p_n)=L(f,p_n)$ so the function is integratable and:
$$\int_1^2 \frac{1}{x}=ln(2)$$

Comment: You have dropped some $\lim_{n \to \infty}$'s in the discussion, which leads to some technically incorrect statements.